# delete_many() not deleting all [PyMongo]

Tags: python-3.x, pymongo

I've recently started using PyMongo as an interface with MongoDB. But I'm having some strange issues when deleting documents from a collection.

Here is an example:

```
from bson import ObjectId
from pymongo import MongoClient

# Open connection
client = MongoClient(mongo_html)
collection_post = client["MyCollection"].posts

# Delete procedure
_ids_to_delete = [ObjectID("xxxxxxx..."), ..., ObjectID("xxxxxxx...")]
n_to_delete = len(_ids_to_delete)
result = collection_post.delete_many({'_id': {'$in': _ids_to_delete}})
n_delete = result.deleted_count

if n_delete != n_to_delete:
    raise Exception("Well well well...")
```

Now, I know for a fact that all the documents in _ids_to_delete exist in the database, in fact, if I run the following if the exception is raised

```
if n_delete != n_to_delete:
    for _id in _ids_to_delete:
         search_result = collection_post.find({'_id': _id})
```

It will **still** find documents that were supposed to be deleted. To get around this, I tried using delete_one() instead and looping, with similar results.

Am I missing something here? Does the fact that another process on an another computer is writing to the same collection at the same time have this effect?

Comment: are all the _ids_to_delete present in the database? And to check weather a document exists use fnd_one() instead of find() like search_result = collection_post.find_one({'_id': _id})

Comment: @daemon24
Yep! All are present in the database, usually delete_many() leaves a few stragglers behind, which I then proceed to delete with delete_one().